# view images in ios7 app and make interactive

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

ok guys im not to shure where to start with this one its a first for me but i have a floor plan that i would like to show in my IOS7 App and i know i want the user to shrink and grow the image so he or she can zoom in to areas of the map.  it would be nice if they could click on the an area of the image and it would be linked to data in my parse database. but i think thats a long way off for me.....

but for now just to let the user shrink and grow and rotate the image would be nice.

anyone got any tutorials they can point me to?

Comment: is the floor map image large?

Comment: At the moment i am designing it i have it in a Vector and a PDF the PDF is 456Kb in file size and bigger than an A4 so nice and clean

Comment: http://www.dmkitservices.com/images/FloorPlan.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Apple's PhotoScroller example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html). [Here an ARC-ready version](https://github.com/robertwalker/PhotoScroller).

This will not cover rotating the image, but you can easily get this by following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more).